# How can I download the image using universal image loader before the activity starts?

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my Universal Image Loader which is working fine. It downloads the image and then displays it, but you can see the change between the default image and the downloaded image. I would like to load the image to be loaded in a previous activity and to display it in this one directly, without that change that I can see. How can I achieve this and how can I download and display new picture when I click a button ? I use the rotation because I get a portrait view and the device displays it in landscape. Can I somehow display them automatically in portrait/landscape based on how they are ?

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_after_login);

        // UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
        DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheOnDisc(true).cacheInMemory(true)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                getApplicationContext())
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
                .discCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024).build();

        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
        // END - UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP

        //your image url
        String url = "imageUrl";

        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisc(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.defaultimage)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.defaultimage)
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.defaultimage).build();

//initialize image view
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageFromServer);
        imageView.setRotation(270);

//download and display image from url
        imageLoader.displayImage(url, imageView, options);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You download the image in the previous activity and write it to a file on disk.  Then pass the name of that file (or use a fixed name) to this activity and load it from disk.  Fairly easy, you'd just need to make sure not to start the activity until the download is done-  otherwise you'll see the delay here.

Comment: I've been trying to do that, but I couldn't do it because I don't know how to actually save them in cache and after that retrieve from cache and display them. Could you give me an example ?